# Deep Pattern matching with repeating arguments

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a function that accepts a single argument that is described by the following grammar:

```
term := (Less | Greater | Equal | LessEqual | GreaterEqual)[Symbol,Number] 
argument := term | Or[term,term,...]
```

The expressions are generated from operations like:

```
Reduce[x^2 -x -6x == 0, x, Reals] // FullForm
(* Or[Equal[x,-2],Equal[x,3]] *)
```

I want to use a pattern in the function definition to ensure that the argument is of the correct form and I want to convert the argument into the following form for use within the function:

```
List[term,...]
```

I am currently bogged down in pattern purgatory. I have tried all of the following and am confused by the results.

```
(* Test data *)
s = Or[Equal[x,-2],GreaterEqual[x,3]]
```

This pattern matched the test case. So far so good.

```
(* case 1 *)
s /. Or[(Less | Greater | Equal | LessEqual | GreaterEqual)
    [x_Symbol, (_Integer | _Rational | _Real)] ..] :> {2}
(* {2} V {2} *)
```

Let's see if we can capture the head in a variable. Yes, we can. I've got this figured out.

```
(* case 2 *)
s /. f_Symbol[(Less | Greater | Equal | LessEqual | GreaterEqual)
    [x_Symbol, (_Integer | _Rational | _Real)] ..] :> {f}
(* {Or} *)
```

Let's limit the pattern to a specific head instead of any symbol. This didn't match. I'm not clear on why.

```
(* case 3 *)
s /. f_Or[(Less | Greater | Equal | LessEqual | GreaterEqual)
     [x_Symbol, (_Integer | _Rational | _Real)] ..] :> {f}
(* No Match *)
```

Maybe a different syntax will work. And it does, but I expected `{Or}` as a result.

```
(* case 4 *)
s /. f : (Or)[(Less | Greater | Equal | LessEqual | GreaterEqual)
     [x_Symbol, (_Integer | _Rational | _Real)] ..] :> {f}
(* {x == -2} V {x >= 3} *)
```

**Edit**:
  Some appropriately placed parens make a difference. I understand this result, but I still don't understand the previous one.

```
(* case 5)
s /. (f : Or)[(Less | Greater | Equal | LessEqual | GreaterEqual)
    [x_Symbol, (_Integer | _Rational | _Real)] ..] :> {f}
(* {Or} *)
```

**End Edit**

I am missing something important about how patterns/rules work. I would like to correct that gap in knowledge. And, secondarily, I'd like to get my function to only accept an appropriate argument and be able to convert the argument into the desired format.

Comment: `f_Or` won't match `Or[f]` because it is already evaluated and becomes `f`

Comment: `f_Or` matches something with head `Or`, not exactly `Or`. So, `_Or[stuff]` matches `Or[something][stuff]`

Comment: @Rojo Does that same logic apply to f_Symbol? Because the pattern with f_Symbol[...] matches while the one with f_Or[...] does not. I assumed that f_Or was simply a more specific version of f_Symbol. Is that not the case?

Comment: @rm-rf Why would f_Or ever match Or[f]? I am not following that part of your comment. I do understand why you need to use HoldPattern for Or[f].

Comment: It is not the case. `Symbol` is a symbol, and `Or` is another symbol. One isn't a subset of the other. All symbols have the "invisible head" `Symbol`. With that in mind, `Or` matches `_Symbol`. `f_Or` would be "equivalent" to `f:Or[___]` which would be a subset of `f:_Symbol[___]`

Comment: @RandomBits It won't... I thought that's what you were trying to do (which I realize wasn't what you were trying to do)

Comment: @Rojo That definitely fills in some of the gaps in my understanding. Most of the examples make sense now. Given your explanation, though, what is the difference in cases 3 and 4 above?

Comment: `Or` mathces `Or`, but `_Or` doesn't. I would only repeat myself saying more. Try to think it through and ask again if you still have doubts

Comment: Sorry I was being so dense. I was equating `f_Or` and `f:(Or)` as different syntax for the same construct (cases 3 & 4). Of course, they are not: `f_Or` is the same as `f:(_Or)`. All the cases make sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just this?

```
f[expr_] := Flatten[{expr /. Or -> List}]

f /@ {Reduce[x == 4, x, Reals], Reduce[x^2 == 4, x, Reals], 
      Reduce[x^2 > 4, x, Reals], Reduce[x^2 >= 4, x, Reals], 
      Reduce[x^2 < 4, x, Reals]}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the comments to my question above, @Rojo et. al. helped me figure out what I was missing with using patterns.

Based on that help I was able to figure out the answer to the second part of my question. Here is the code that I am using:

```
Remove[ftermQ];
Remove[f];
ftermQ[expr_] := Module[
  {
    termQ = MatchQ[#, (Less | Greater | Equal | LessEqual | GreaterEqual)] &,
    numberQ = MatchQ[#, (_Integer | _Rational | _Real)] &
   },
   MatchQ[expr, _?termQ[_Symbol, _?numberQ]] || 
    MatchQ[expr, Inequality[_, Less, _Symbol, Less, _]] ||
    MatchQ[expr, Inequality[_, LessEqual, _Symbol, LessEqual, _]] 
]

f[term_?ftermQ | HoldPattern[Or[term : (_?ftermQ) ..]]] := {term}

f /@ {Reduce[x == 4, x, Reals],
      Reduce[x^2 == 4, x, Reals],
      Reduce[x^2 > 4, x, Reals],
      Reduce[x^2 >= 4, x, Reals],
      Reduce[x^2 < 4, x, Reals]}
(**
    {{x==4},
     {x==-2,x==2},
     {x<-2,x>2},
     {x<=-2,x>=2},
     {-2<x<2}}
**)
```

At this point the only obvious issue is the `pattern::patv` messages produced because I use `term_` as both a single and multiple element.